# NullReferenceException Json.NET Xamarin.Android android 4.3

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

I believe I have just run into this bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4902 on my Nexus 4 now that I have updated to android 4.3.

Basically, when JSON.NET tries to get the timezone via the mono runtime, we get a null reference exception because there are issues with an environment variable in certain android builds.

The same code worked fine before I updated and still works fine on other android devices. Are there any workarounds available for this? Is there anything else I can do or am I stuck? Has anyone else run into it recently?

Is there a fix planned in the near future?

Comment: @WilliamGrand This is still an issue, I've basically had to code around it for now... What I've done is instead of having DateTime properties, I have string properties and then manually handle the serialization that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin 4.8.2 (alpha) fixes this problem.  (As of Sep 3, 2013)