# Xamarin.Android JSON.Net serilization fails on 4.2.2 device only TimeZoneNotFound exception

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.android, json.net

I am using JSON.Net to serialize a DTO and I am getting the following exception on the physical device. THis works on all other devices we have tested on, but is failing on the `Samsung Galaxy Tab 3lite SM-T110` running version 4.2.2.

I was having [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451333/nullreferenceexception-json-net-xamarin-android-android-4-3) but when I upgraded to Xamarin 3.0, it turned into this below:

```
06-03 21:17:41.687 E/mono-rt (22071): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: Exception of type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException' was thrown.
06-03 21:17:41.687 E/mono-rt (22071):   at System.TimeZoneInfo.get_Local () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 21:17:41.687 E/mono-rt (22071):   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DateTimeUtils.GetUtcOffset (DateTime d) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 21:17:41.687 E/mono-rt (22071):   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DateTimeUtils.WriteDateTimeString (System.Char[] chars, Int32 start, DateTime value, Nullable`1 offset, DateTimeKind kind, DateFormatHandling format) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 21:17:41.687 E/mono-rt (22071):   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WriteValue (DateTime value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 21:17:41.687 E/mono-rt (22071):   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteValue (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, PrimitiveTypeCode typeCode, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-03 21:17:41.687 E/mono-rt (22071):   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializePrimitive (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, System.Object value, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonPrimitiveContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.
06-03 21:17:41.695 I/mono-stdout(22071): Executing Command: UpdateRegistration
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**EDIT** This is the DTO that I am trying to serialize. You can see when the constructor gets called, it sets it to `DateTime.Now`. Shouldnt this just assume the local timezone?

```
  public class RecordTargetFrequency : BaseCommand, ICommand {
        public Guid TargetId { get; private set; }
        public Guid? LocationId { get; private set; }
        public Guid TherapistId { get; private set; }
        public bool? Increase { get; private set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; private set; }

        public RecordTargetFrequency(Guid targetId, Guid? locationId, Guid therapistId, bool? increase) {
            TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            TargetId = targetId;
            LocationId = locationId;
            TherapistId = therapistId;
            Increase = increase;
        }

        public void Validate() {
            ValidateGuid(TargetId);
            ValidateGuid(TherapistId);
        }
    }
```

I am then serializing it with this line:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(executedCommand);
```

Comment: Can you debug the code, or put a log entry in there, and figure out what presumably is being passed as a time zone that the code considers invalid?

Comment: Does Java.Util.TimeZone.Default give you any value on the device?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have added some additional code

Comment: @SKall I am getting a timezone back from Java.Util.TimeZone.Default. Eastern Standard Time America/New York

Comment: Xamarin.Android has had quite a few TimeZone issues.

This sounds like it is to do with https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18791 and https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4902

I'd suggest you log this with Xamarin support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `TimeZoneInfo.Local` is somewhat broken on Mono. I've seen three different failure modes here:

- Returning a time zone which acts correctly, but has an ID of "Local"
- Returning a null reference
- Throwing an exception

I don't have a good solution for that, *but* if you're trying to record a timestamp, it would be a much better idea to use `DateTime.UtcNow` anyway. Then you don't need to worry about time zones at all. In *most* cases, you should be storing and handling date/time values just in terms of an instant in time, without caring about the time zone or even which calendar is involved.

If you can get a time zone ID from `Java.Util.TimeZone.Default` as it looks like you can - you'd want `America/New_York` here - then another alternative is to use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project, which includes the IANA database. So you could create a `ZonedDateTime` which represents exactly what you need. We support Json.NET serialization too, so that part shouldn't be a problem.

Again though, I would encourage you to just use UTC unless you *really* need the local time.

A couple more options - you might want to consider using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`; if you're just trying to serialize the value as "a date and time with a UTC offset" then `DateTimeOffset.Now` might do *exactly* what you want.

(If none of this helps, please give more context as to what you need and what you expect the JSON to look like.)

Comment: Using DateTime.UtcNow instead of DateTime.Now nailed this one for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check you time setting for the device. This usually happens when you device time has a wrong time set. Even the time is correct, check if the Time zone is the correct one (eg. for me it's GMT -3 = Greenwich time -3 hours)

A good test is to set it by your self. Sometimes the carrier doesn't give you the correct timezone.

This setting is in System > Date & Time setting.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, the problem comes down to the internal use of `TimeZoneInfo.Local` on non-Windows devices, but you can avoid this.

If you follow through the source code of [`DateTimeUtils.WriteDateTimeString`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/6.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DateTimeUtils.cs#L428), you'll find that you need to do two things:

1. Switch to `DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat`.  This should be the default anyway, and is the recommended best practice.
2. Switch to `DateTime.UtcNow`.  It usually doesn't make sense to send local times to the server anyway.  If for some reason you do, then try serializing a `DateTimeOffset` instead, and use `DateTimeOffset.Now`.